# R only using 13% of my processor

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, processing-efficiency, cpu-cores

**System:**

OS - **Windows 7**

RAM - **8GB**

Processor - **Intel i7**

R version - **Always keep it up-to-date**

**Problem:**

R is using only 13% (i.e. 1 out of 8 cores) of my Intel i7 Processor. I want to tap multiple cores for running my code faster. But unfortunately unable to.

**Attempts:**

Started using Parallel, Snow, Snowfall packages, even configured them to use 8 cores, but unfortunately, I'm not using any of the apply functions to make use of the custom functions they provide (like mcapply, sflapply).

```
for (i in 1:number.of.accounts){
  if (is.na(s$rev2012[i]) == "FALSE" && is.na(s$rev2013[i]) == "TRUE"){
    loss = rbind(loss, s[i,])
  }
  x = x + 1
}
```

The data frame "s" in the above code has about 56,000 rows with 14 columns. "rev" stands for Revenue. What I'm trying to do is, if there is revenue in 2012, but not in 2013, then we "lost" that customer. I'm using "x" to keep a count on the speed.

This piece of code takes ton of time to run, and I've not yet let it finish. When I interrupt, I see that not much has progressed.

Any help in unlocking all the cores to run this piece of code would be really great.

Thanks!

Comment: I find it easiest to use `foreach` for parallel computing on Windows. However, the speed-up you can achieve by parallelization is extremely limited (by the number of CPUs). If you rewrite your code to a vectorized approach instead of a `for` loop you can expect a speed-up by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Try `loss <- s[!is.na(s$rev2012) & is.na(s$rev2013),]`. That doesn't parallelize it, but instead uses the vectorized form for which R is optimized.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395309/how-to-make-r-use-all-processors

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

Roland, could you please help me with a pseudo-code for `foreach`? Unable to find help for it.

shadow, thanks for your code. I'm trying it now. Will update if I see any improvements.

I'm still looking for unlocking my cores specifically.

Comment: http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/parallel-computing-r-windows-using-dosnow-foreach/

Comment: Thanks a lot Raffael. I'll try and update here.

Answer (score 2):

Because R does not natively support parallel processing, you have to add some boilerplate to your script to make it utilize all 8 cores.

Check out the **doParallel** package.  Here is a [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf) showing how to use the **doParallel** package.  Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734748/trying-to-get-started-with-doparallel-and-foreach-but-no-improvement) about how to use chunking to speed up performance.

That will require you to use a `foreach` loop, which can be parallelized with `%dopar%`, instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: doParallel is doing the magic, but it's using 6+ GB of my RAM (out of 8GB), and the processor usage is less than 3% (not even 13% as before).
Overall, the code is running for a long time still (>10 mins)
`foreach (i = 1:number.of.accounts) %dopar% 
  if (is.na(s$rev2012[i]) == "FALSE" && is.na(s$rev2013[i]) == "TRUE"){
    loss = rbind(loss, s[i,])
  } `

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two problems with your code. First, you are evaluating row-wise using a for loop. There are virtually no circumstances where this is good practice in R. Second, you are appending one row at a time to `loss`. This is also extremely slow.

Using parallel processing will provide at most an 8-fold improvement. Vectorizing will provide a greater than 50-fold improvement, and using `data.tables` will improve even further.

```
df <- data.frame(rev2012=sample(c(NA,1:99),56000,replace=T),
                 rev2013=sample(c(NA,1:99),56000,replace=T))
df   <- cbind(df,matrix(rnorm(56000*12),ncol=12))

for.loop <- function(){
  loss <- c()
  for (i in 1:nrow(df))
    if (is.na(df$rev2012[i]) == "FALSE" && is.na(df$rev2013[i]) == "TRUE") loss = rbind(loss, df[i,])
}

df.vectorized <- function(){
  loss <- with(df,df[!is.na(rev2012) & is.na(rev2013),])
}

library(data.table)
dt <- function(){
  dt <- data.table(df)
  setkey(dt,rev2012,rev2013)
  loss <- dt[!is.na(rev2012)&is.na(rev2013)]
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(for.loop(),df.vectorized(),dt(),times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#             expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#       for.loop() 3141.53686 3431.99529 3620.90536 3845.81394 3875.92435    10
#  df.vectorized()   38.76076   55.01082   58.97976   64.19538   67.33192    10
#             dt()   28.20870   31.10005   40.54224  165.20777  184.48776    10
```

The reason data tables only improve by about 33%  over the vectorized data frame approach is that 56,000 rows is not all that large. If `df` had >1e6 rows, using `data.table` would definitely be the best option.

Comment: The s added to data.table is bugging me :(

Comment: At the end you have `data.tables` instead of `data.table` a few times.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your code and your explanation. However, I had to kill the process because this too was taking long time (>10 mins) to execute.

Comment: @Pragith I believe you misunderstood something. The data.table solution should be extremely fast.